# Uploading to another domain gives HTTP code 405

Tags: iis, file-upload, http-headers, cross-domain, plupload

I'm trying to upload a file (which can be quite large) from the website of one server to the backend of another server using plupload. Lets say:

```
domain 1 = http://www.websitedomain.com/uploadform
domain 2 = http://www.backenddomain.com/uploadhandler
```

Trying to upload i send the following:

```
OPTIONS /main/uploadnetwork.php HTTP/1.1
Host: backenddomain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://www.websitedomain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://www.websitedomain.com/uploadform
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
DNT: 1
```

But when I try to start the upload the server returns the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
Date: Mon, 01 Oct 2012 12:41:57 GMT
Content-Length: 999
```

After doing some research I found out that a browser does this to check if the server will accept the intended message. It looks like my server doesn't feel like accepting a simple POST call even tho i use post all the time.

The Google Chrome console gives the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.backenddomain.com/uploadhandler. Origin http://www.websitedomain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Does anyone know how to stop the browser from checking or how i can tell my server to just accept the POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to face a [Same origin policy problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Adding a special header should help on some browsers :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answers to this question might also be helpfull :
[Cross-domain data access in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1244182/1236044)

You should also check the cross-domain tag : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-domain

Comment: re: "Adding a special header should help on some browsers", actually CORS works on all browsers that support the HTML5 plupload plugin, and this even includes IE10. Call it a coincidence if you like, but seems no vendor implemented just upload support without also adding CORS.

Comment: I found the solution te be quite easy. The receiving server doesn't know the sender and doesn't accept. Adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header fixed the problem!